# How to use webClient in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-integration, webclient, spring-webclient

I'm trying to use `webClient` in my Spring Integration application.
Using `block()` method i got this error:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@28b67bb]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-4
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
```

So I removed the `block` to prevent the issue but I looks like the calling is not executing without that. I don't know how make it work

**Activator**

```
@ServiceActivator(
    inputChannel = "lisContractValidationChannel",
    outputChannel = "aopContractValidationReplyAndContinueRouterChannel"

)
public Application sendEContract(Application application) {
    
    ContractRequest contractRequest = prepareRequest(application);
    
    lisOperations.verifyContract(contractRequest,
        application.getContractData().getRouteOne().getConversationID(),
        application.getRouteOneId());
    
    return application;
}
```

**Operations**

```
private final WebClient webClient;

@Override
public void verifyContract(
    EContractRequest contractRequest,
    String vendorTransactionId,
    String loanId) {

    
    webClient.post()
        .uri(baseUrl + contract)
        .header("sourceRequestId", sourceRequestId)
        .header("VENDOR-ID", String.join(";", List.of(vendorId, vendorTransactionId, loanId)))
        .bodyValue(contractRequest).retrieve().toEntity(LisResponse.class);
}
```

**WebClient Configuration**

```
@Bean
public WebClient webClient(MetricsDTWebClientFilterFunction metricsDTWebClientFilterFunction) {
    
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
        .create();
    
    final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .codecs(ClientCodecConfigurer::defaultCodecs)
        .filter(metricsDTWebClientFilterFunction);
    
    return webClientBuilder.build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `webClient` is reactive component and any Reactive Streams solution requires a subscription for their execution. And what is more important it is recommended to do them non-blocking way. That's why you got such a Block Hound error for using that `block()` operator.

Since `toEntity()` returns a `Mono` for us you simply can use its `subscribe()` to initiate a request execution.  It may exit immediately from your `verifyContract()` though just because an execution may happen on a different thread.

This way you may consider to change a contract of your `verifyContract()` to a `Mono` to propagate it downstream for subscription in their calls.

Please, learn more about Project Reactor to make yourself familiar with all of this blocking and non-blocking stuff: https://projectreactor.io/

Comment: I made ```verifyContract``` returns ```Mono``` and the activator execute ```suscribe()``` like: ```lisOperations.verifyEContract(contractRequest, application.getContractData().getRouteOne().getConversationID(), application.getRouteOneId()).subscribe();``` But my test is falling because is not executing it (I have mocked the external call using ```wiremock```)

Comment: As I said: reactive is async in most cases, so your test is probably exiting too early without waiting for your request execution.

Comment: how long ```subscribe()```  takes to been executed?

Comment: It depends how busy threads are for other stuff to let your request to be executed in that `WebClient`. As I said: you can propagate that `Mono` all the way up to the code you execute in your test. And there you indeed can call `block()` on it. The point is that it is better to avoid `block()` in the production code.